# Twitter Bootstrap - Center a tag with display:block inside a thumbnail?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center my a .img-link tag within a thumbnail but haven't had any luck.

Here is a link to an example of what I am doing http://jsfiddle.net/Dhk3M/ .

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give **.thumbnail** `text-align:center`. Write like this:

```
.thumbnail {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Dhk3M/1/

Answer (score 1):

to auto center an element, it has to have a fixed width so you can apply `margin-left: auto;`
and `margin-right: auto;`

```
.img-link img {
    width: 267px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

this is valid if you can actually set the element width in your css, that means you know the element will always have the exact same width. alternatively:

```
text-align: center;
```

will work for inline elements (like an img tag)

Comment: I can't have a fixed width because I have multiple thumbnails like this and each has a different width. Is there another way to do this? Otherwise I could dynamically set the width as an inline style.

Comment: I don't think it actually needs a fixed width does it?

Comment: unfortunately it does need a fixed width if you want margin: auto; to be applied, however width does not apply to inline elements :)